# Is there a way to put the column filters in a react bootstrap table above the rows of the table rather than below?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap-table

I have a react BootstrapTable and I need column filters. I added `columnFilter` to the mix and got nice filters below the table. Is there a way to move them above the rows of the table and below the headers?

It looks like this:

```
            <BootstrapTable
                version='4'
                hover
                condensed
                options={options}
                search
                columnFilter
                pagination
                exportCSV
                data={records}
                multiColumnSearch={true}
                expandableRow={false}
            >
```

Is there some optional value to the `columnFilter` attribute? or any other way to move the row of filters upwards?